# How to insert today's date in SQL select statement using python?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql

I'm trying to send today variable into SQL but it is not working.

```
import datetime from date

today = date.today()


stmt = "select agent_email from customer_interaction_fact where to_date(DT) >= + today + ORDER BY CONVERSATION_CREATED_TIME DESC"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to compute today's date in Python. Just use the PostgreSQL function [`CURRENT_DATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT):

```
stmt = "SELECT ... WHERE TO_DATE(DT) >= CURRENT_DATE ..."
```

Comment: This is the only answer I would consider; also worth pointing out the front end app should be aware of the TimeZone used by the server/should make sure that entries are written with a TimeZone that means "current_date" makes sense from the perspective of the user. Problems arise with the notion of "current" if the front end writes TimeZoneless dates that the back end then assumes are in a different time zone

Answer (score 0):

What database engine you're using? You'd need to convert the python `datetime` object into string with format accepted by the database.

```
# In case YYYY-MM-DD
today_str = str(today)

stmt = f"""select agent_email 
           from customer_interaction_fact 
           where to_date(DT) >= datetime({today}, "YYYY-MM-DD") 
           order by CONVERSATION_CREATED_TIME DESC"""
```

Another solution, assuming the client (your program) is in the same timezone as the database engine, you could use your database engine `datetime.now` function. In `SQLite` for instance `datetime('now')`

Answer (score -1):

try like below

```
from datetime import date

today = date.today()


stmt = "select agent_email,aht_in_secs,queueid,EFFORTSCORE from facts.public.customer_interaction_fact where agent_email <> 'Bot' and aht_in_secs is not NULL and to_date(DT) >=" + today + "ORDER BY CONVERSATION_CREATED_TIME DESC"
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, but unfortunately it did not work. However, it is resolved using CURRENT_DATE instead of passing variable.